# How to version an API such that one version of the api will require a bearer token and the other version does not

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an asp.net core web api. Say if i want to have two versions of the api such that, version 1 will require a bearer token and version 2 will not require the barer token.

Since the token configuration code resides in the startup.cs file, how do I have two startup.cs files to match my requirement above? i am not even sure if it is legal to have two startup.cs files targeting two different versions of the api because the code to configure versioning of an asp.net core api will also reside in the startup.cs file.

Let me know what options are available to achieve my requirement above.

My current startup.cs file with token authentication enabled look like this..

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AzureADSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        var azureADSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureADSettings>();
        var validAudience = new List<string>
        {
            azureADSettings.Audience
        };



        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = $"{azureADSettings.Instance}/{azureADSettings.TenantId}/";
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                //azureADSettings.Audience
                ValidAudiences = new List<string>(validAudience)
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: Could you put a a section in appsettings like this `"Auth": true`, Then call  Configuration.GetSection("Auth"); to find out if this version is using auth, and then put an if statement before the `AddAuthentication`

Answer (score 1):

The `Authorize` middleware applies that check if you do not explicitly a controller or action as `Anonymous`. Maybe what you can do is:

1. Put the `[Anonymous]` attribute on top of your controller(s).
2. Mark your v1 API end-points in your controller(s) as `[Authorize]`.
3. Leave the v2 API end-points as-is.

This way, the v2 API end-points should work fine with users not having a bearer token but v1 API end-points should expect a valid bearer token.

Comment: I think this should work! i keep the question open in order to see if there are other options!! thanks!